# Python Socket programming (TCP vs. UDP)

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp, twisted

I'm planning to design a server that receives data from multiple clients, the server don't need to send anything back to the client, though STATUS_OK is still cool but not necessary.

I know the basics of Python socket module, twisted framework but my question is,  should i use UDP or TCP? The client that need to stay connected at all.

I hope you guys understand my question, thank you for your wonderful help here

Comment: ""unlimited amount"" - what a vague requirement...continue dreaming that you can handle "unlimited" with *one* server.

Comment: @RestRisiko clearly he means "unbounded", or "indeterminate", not infinite. This is more a question about basic networking concepts like buffering.

Comment: Actually now I'm not sure. Are you asking about an unlimited number of clients, or an unlimited amount of data from the client?

Comment: @Chris: and your point is? You both have none

Comment: @rest: your comments aren't exactly helpful to the OP.

Comment: @RestRisiko either ask for clarification, or give an answer. Berating the OP about "vague requirements" is a waste of text.

Comment: Sorry if i use Unlimited, but what i really meant is concurrent connections, client don`t need to stay connected, client only send in data once and get disconnected. thanks @Chris, @RestRisiko take easy

Comment: What's the ultimate purpose of this? How much data will the clients send? How frequently will they do so?

Answer (score 4):

You should always use TCP until you have a performance problem that you know can be mitigated with UDP.  TCP is easier to understand when it fails.

Answer (score 2):

Can you afford to lose messages? If yes, use UDP. Otherwise use TCP. It's what they're designed for.

Comment: Using TCP i must manually close client connection after i have received message?

Comment: Erm ... many systems that can't afford to "lose" messages use UDP. NFS comes to mind (prior to v3) immediately, as does DNS and DHCP. Depending on what you need, moving the retransmit / sequencing logic to your application *can* make sense.

Comment: if you don't close connections properly, you'll soon find that your "unlimited connections" is not very unlimited at all.

Comment: A better way to say this would be "do you have tests for what happens when you lose messages"?  Lots of novices think they can afford to lose messages at the application level, but don't realize that their underlying protocol is stateful somehow and lost messages cause bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I would use TCP in your situation, but it's hard to tell what the specifics of your needs are. TCP is in most cases a better protocol because it's much more reliable. Data is very rarely lost in TCP, however this does slow it down a bit. Since you're not sending anything back to the client, the fact that TCP is a streaming protocol shouldn't really matter too much.

So I'd just go with TCP.

Answer (score -1):

For how long will one client be connected to the server? How many concurrent connections are you planning to handle? If there will be very short bursts of data for a lot of clients, then you should go with UDP. But chances are, TCP will do just fine initially.

Comment: Clients only need to send in data once and disconnect, for now, i can`t predict the amount of concurrent clients